# error:no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ifstream<char>::open(std::__cxx11::string&, const openmode&)’

Tags: c++, g++

I made a C++ program that generates an "inverted index"of all the words in a list of text files in Visual Studio Code. When I go to run and compile the code in Linux using g++ I get the said error.

Here is the code with the issue:

```
    sub_fin.open(fileName[fileNumber], ios::in);
    sub_fin >> word[WordCounter];
    word[WordCounter] = PureAlphabetStr(word[WordCounter]);
```

Comment: `sub_fin.open(fileName[fileNumber].c_str()` You are using very old g++.

Comment: This fixed my main error. Thank you